# Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+S does not work in Microsoft Excel 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, filesystems

I try to save an Excel file with Ctrl+S, but that does not seem to work.

In particular, when I close the file, Excel asks: "Want to save your changes to ... ?" If I press "Don't Save", the changes made before pressing Ctrl+S are not saved.

If I press "Save" from the File menu, then Excel does not ask "Want to save your changes to ... ?", and the changes are indeed saved.

**Ctrl+S is working in other applications. I am having this problem only with Excel.**

Can one explain this behavior and teach me how to make Ctrl+S work with Excel?

**Added:** There seem to be no active add-ins:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl-S works fine in Excel 2016 as well as in all previous versions of Excel.

Start Excel in [Safe Mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72) to ensure there are no add-ins messing up your shortcut keys.

Does Ctrl-S now save the workbook?

If so, you have some software installed that overrides the Ctrl-S keyboard shortcut. Remove that software and Excel will respond correctly to Ctrl-S again.

**Edit:** To find the offending add-in, remove all add-ins. Then see if Ctrl-S works. Bring back one add-in at a time and test after each activation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. Indeed, Ctrl+S works in Safe Mode. Do you have any suggestions on how to find the offending application that overrides Ctrl+S for Excel, or maybe how to override that override?

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your further suggestion. Alas, there seem to have been no active Excel add-ins (see the snapshot added to my question), and yet Ctrl+S still is not working in the normal mode. Moreover, the changes saved by Ctrl+S in Safe Mode do not appear if I reopen the file in the normal mode. What is baffling and frustrating is that such unwelcome behavior appears to be only in Excel.

Comment: In fact, the changes saved through the File menu in Safe Mode do not appear either if I reopen the file in the normal mode.

Comment: These are Excel Add-ins. What about COM Add-ins?

Comment: The offending COM add-in was DriveForOffice. Thank you very much for your patience leading me to the solution. However, I am appalled by Excel and switching to LibreOffice, which seems much nicer overall and in particulars.